# How to view what is inside string.IsNullOrEmpty, by example

Tags: reflector

I installed Reflector extension for VS from here
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77/
(I have VS 2012, this version is not in supported list but extension installed succesfylly)

Then I click "Analyze" on System.dll in ".NET Reflector object browser", but I don't see System.String in the list. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I analyzed all assemblies, and then right click -> "Go to definition":

[image]